# Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Does a result proved for the metric $d$ apply to every metric $d^{'}$ on $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Does a result proved for the metric $d$ apply to every metric $d^{'}$ on $X$ ?

Very often a statement involving $\mathbb R^n$ is proved by applying the metric $d_{Eu}$.

An example of this is the following statement:

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb R^n$

$K$ is bounded and closed $\iff$ $K$ is compact

In my textbook the statement is proved by applying the Euclidean metric $d_{Eu}$. However the statement does not say anything about $d_{Eu}$.

**This has made me think that it is enough to prove a statement for a single metric $d$ in order to prove it for every metric $d^{'}$ ?**

In general to prove a statement like the one above, should I only prove it for a single $d$ metric and then mention it holds for that particular metric - then does the statement holds for other metrics $d^{'}$ ?

Comment: Note that the property "bounded" depends on $d$. In fact you can replace a metry $d(x,y)$ with $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$, which gives the same topology but makes everything bounded.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with norms on a finite-dimensional vector space, then they are all equivalent meaning they can be bounded in both directions by constant multiples of each other. So if you prove a statement using one norm-metric, the result typically holds for any other norm-metric as well. However there are metrics which are not defined by norms, and in general you should be able to get different results with different metrics, e.g. if you use the metric that defines all distinct points to be distance 1 from each other. Under this metric the entire space is closed and bounded for example, but not compact unless it is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not.  Consider $M_i:=(\boldsymbol R,d_i)$ for $i=1,2$ where $d_1$ is the Euclidian distance and $d_2$ is the discrete metric defined by $d_2(x,y)=0$ iff $ x=y$ and $1$ otherwise. Define $B_i(r):=\{x\in\boldsymbol R\mid d_i(x,0)\leq r\}$. Then, for example, $B_2(1)=\boldsymbol R$ is bounded in $M_2$, that is in respect to $d_2$, but not bounded in $M_1$ in respect to $d_1$.

Comment: Thanks. What is the definition of discrete metric ?

Comment: Wrong question.  Bounded in respect of what meyric?

Comment: Thanks, I understand your reasoning now that I see the definition of the discrete metric. I see it is not enough to prove a statement for a single metric to prove it for all metrics in the case of boundedness.
My statement in OP can be proved both for the discrete metric and the euclidean metric, right (if we use a suitable definition of boundedness in each case)? Could you give me a statement that cannot be proved for one metric, but is proveable for another ?